# Not able to export to Excel in primefaces using data exporter

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to export a data table to excel using primefaces 5.1, poi 3.9. My xhtml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="custom.css" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="customjs.js" />

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable id="tbl" var="tempEmployeeInOut"
                value="#{tempInOut.tempEmployeeInOuts}"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {Exporters}"
                paginator="true" rows="10" style="margin-bottom:20px">

                <f:facet name="{Exporters}">
                        <h:commandLink>
                        <p:graphicImage library="images" name="excel.png" width="24" />
                        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tbl" fileName="tempEmployeeInOut" />
                    </h:commandLink>

                    <h:commandLink>
                        <p:graphicImage library="images" name="pdf.png" width="24" />
                        <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl" fileName="tempEmployeeInOut" />
                    </h:commandLink>

                    <h:commandLink>
                        <p:graphicImage library="images" name="csv.png" width="24" />
                        <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="tbl" fileName="tempEmployeeInOut" />
                    </h:commandLink>

                    <h:commandLink>
                        <p:graphicImage library="images" name="xml.png" width="24" />
                        <p:dataExporter type="xml" target="tbl" fileName="tempEmployeeInOut" />
                    </h:commandLink>
                </f:facet>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Employee Id" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{tempEmployeeInOut.empID}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Name" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{tempEmployeeInOut.name}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Entry Date" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{tempEmployeeInOut.entryDate}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Morning In Time" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{tempEmployeeInOut.morInTime}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Lunch Out Time" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{tempEmployeeInOut.lunchOutTime}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Lunch In Time" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{tempEmployeeInOut.lunchInTime}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="OutTime" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{tempEmployeeInOut.outTime}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

            <h3>Export Page Data Only</h3>
            <h:commandLink>
                <p:graphicImage library="images" name="excel.png" />
                <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tbl" fileName="cars"
                    pageOnly="true" />
            </h:commandLink>

            <h:commandLink>
                <p:graphicImage library="images" name="pdf.png" />
                <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl" fileName="cars"
                    pageOnly="true" />
            </h:commandLink>

            <h:commandLink>
                <p:graphicImage library="images" name="csv.png" />
                <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="tbl" fileName="cars"
                    pageOnly="true" />
            </h:commandLink>

            <h:commandLink>
                <p:graphicImage library="images" name="xml.png" />
                <p:dataExporter type="xml" target="tbl" fileName="cars"
                    pageOnly="true" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:form>

    </h:form>


</h:body>


</html>
```

I have nothing special in my TempInOut class. I am able to display my data into the data table. But when I am clicking the export to excel icon or any other icon, nothing is happening except the url have one # appended. I searched at many places but mostly there were version issue. I am not able understand where I am doing wrong.

my data table looks something like this.

[image: Export to excel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add **Apache POI** dependecies?

If not,
you download the latest stable version from [Apache POI download page](http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.10.1), extract downloaded file, put library in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and re-run webapp on server.

Or if you're using Maven, copy and paste this dependecies on you pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
  <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes I have added the poi jar into my /WEB-INF/lib folder I tried with version 3.9 and 3.7 but no luck.

Comment: Your posted code is incomplete. Did you try to run primefaces showcase example on your webapp? Did you put your datatable inside a form?

Comment: thanks for the reply @giaffa86, I am implementing the primefaces dataexporter in my project the way it's given in showcase. No I didn't try to run the example. I didn't post the full code, as it's  too big.

Comment: I just tried primefaces showcase example, and after adding apache poi dependencies, it worked. So did you put a form container? If yes, you should edit your post and show us missing parts.

Comment: Have you noticed that there are two nested h:form?

Comment: Thank you giaffa86, that was the problem !!